# Algorithm for equal division of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, grouping, division

I need an algorithm to make equal division of an array of values. I will demonstrate in JavaScript but any language can be applied.

I have an Array of values ​​with random quantity and values
EX:

```
[5,9,14,18,19,29,49,59,89,99,129,159,189,199,259,299,599]
```

(One feature I've noticed is that values ​​grow exponentially)

I need to divide this array into a fixed number of groups, so that all have a close quantity of items and the difference of the first item with the last one is not very large between the groups.
In this case, I will divide into 4 groups.

THE PROBLEM:
If I divide into 4 groups of equal quantities, it may occur that the first item in the group is much smaller than the last in relation to the other groups.
If I divide into 4 groups with equal ranges of values, one group may have few items relative to the others.

I want to get somewhere in the middle, but I have not got a solution yet.

Example of an acceptable solution:

```
[
    [5,9,14,18,19,29],
    [49,59,89,99],
    [129,159,189,199],
    [259,399,599],
]
```

If someone did not understand the question, comment.

APPLICATION: A filter that shows ranges of values.
It will appears like this:

- less than 19
- from 29 to 89
- from 99 to 159
- from 189 to 259
- above 399

what i can't show is something like this:

- from 29 to 399 (very large interval)

Thank you for your help!

---

Large differences - A jump from a small value to a large value

Another possible example to work:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 48, 49, 50, 55, 56, 57, 60, 61, 62, 70, 72, 73, 74, 75, 80, 100, 150, 300]
```

and

```
[830, 1790,1990,1990,2390,2420,2599,2690,2890,3124,3340,3404,3460,3497,3590,3590,3598,3620,3690,3725,3725,3774,3780,3798,3865,3885,3890,3929,3949,3990,3990,3998,4080,4099,4128,4132,4183,4190,4199,4250,4290,4290,4290,4420,4490,4496,4507,4590,4599,4680,4750,4790,4790,4890,4898,4990,4999,5190,5299,5390,5396,5530,5590]
```

Comment: what are the input data?

Comment: Am i correct in assuming your 'small' and 'large' is based on number of digits?

Comment: What is the acceptable margin between groups?

Comment: The question needs more explanation as the desired objective is not bounded. If the input `[a,b]` is to be divided into `1` group `[a,b]` , the difference between `a` and `b` can be arbitrarily large. Perhaps the term [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is relevant, where the number of clusters is given. Apparently the [k-means clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Algorithms) can be used.

Comment: xDreamCoding - Small and large are related to the groups.

Comment: Stamos 1 - the difference between the start and end of groups need to be gradual. The ideal is double of the last group. EX: `[10,20], [20, 40], [40, 80]`

Comment: You say you need to create four groups, but your example shows 5.

Comment: Example fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an approximation with a logarithmic view of the data and to group it in equal intervals.

It works by calculating the index of the result set for pushing the values.

In `test`, you get the whole number, an the first value gets always index zero and the last, a number smaller than the wanted parts (for that, I take a factor smaller than one, because one would move the last item outside of the wanted length of the array).

```js
var data = [5, 9, 14, 18, 19, 29, 49, 59, 89, 99, 129, 159, 189, 199, 259, 299, 599],
    parts = 5,
    smallerThanOne = 0.9999999999999999,
    interval = Math.log(data[data.length - 1] / data[0]),
    test = data.map(function (a) {
        return parts * smallerThanOne * Math.log(a / data[0]) / interval;
    }),
    grouped = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var i = Math.floor(parts * smallerThanOne * Math.log(a / data[0]) / interval);
        r[i] = r[i] || [];
        r[i].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);


console.log(grouped);
console.log(test);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: with the array 
`[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 48, 49, 50, 55, 56, 57, 60, 61, 62, 70, 72, 73, 74, 75, 80, 100, 150, 300]` 
for instance, the first and second sublist become very small in length

Comment: my proposal is just an approach. it works for equaly distributed values which have a logarithmic space. for a better understanding, you could add some more use cases and the wanted outcome, eventualy with some code, you tried.